# Free OCSP server for testing purposes?

Tags: security, certificate, ocsp

Can anyone recommend a free and simple OCSP server for Windows or Linux?

Comment: OCSP definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol

Comment: @Warren if you don't know what ocsp is,  then you shouldn't answer the question.

Comment: @unknown, warren didn't answer, he used a comment to add a link to provide additional information. At the very least it saved me having to look up yet another never before seen acronym.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best free OCSP server is in the [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/) package.  Here is an example of creating a  [custom OCSP message](https://mm.cs.dartmouth.edu/wiki/index.php/OCSP_messages).  If you like java then you should use [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/userguide-ocsp.html).

I think windows has an OCSP server in the windows 2008 enterprise edition.  I know it has other parts of the PKI.  This isn't free.

Comment: There is also Fedora/Redhat's ''Dogtag'' http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page

Comment: @unknown: Thanks, that looks very interesting. I'll give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: @The Rook: I was able to glue a solution using the OpenCA library. See this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/131983/openssl-how-to-setup-an-ocsp-server-for-checking-third-party-certificates. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @StackedCrooked Thats awesome! OpenCA rocks,  i'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 Enterprise Editions both have OCSP as an option when you install the AD Cert Services. You can use both for testing purposes for 180-days. [Download available from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).