# OCSP responder on a virtual host of Apache/Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, openssl, ocsp

Is it possible to run an OCSP responder `openssl ocsp -index ...` on an Apache/Nginx virtual host alongside other virtual hosts? So ocsp.example.com or pki.example.com/ocsp/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/131983/126632

Comment: I did not mean how to configure the responder itself, but how to run the responder on an Apache server so that websites and web applications can be hosted on the same server.

Comment: Not with `openssl ocsp`! That's the whole point.

Comment: OCSP requests are HTTP requests, and both Apache and nginx can (reverse-)proxy HTTP requests -- for a vhost, or certain URLs within one (e.g. your responder URLs) -- to another server either local or remote. Did you try the former?